# How to know when to stop InputStream buffering

Tags: java, inputstream

I communicate with a device through serial port.

I've managed to get the InputStream and read what the device sends.

But the problem is, I simply don't know when to stop reading and proceed to another task.

Here is the simplified code:

```
inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
try
{
    int step = 0;
    while ( (len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1 )
    {
        //do something
    }    
    System.out.println("END");
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new Exception("IO Error");
}
```

It has never managed to reach the "END". It keeps going on a loop even though the device send nothing. How do I stop the loop when the device stops sending.

Comment: what is your len initial value

Answer (score 1):

```
 inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
 int available = inputStream .available();

 if (available > 0) {
        byte data[] = new byte[available];
        inputStream .read(data);

   }else{
    logger.info("data is not avilable");
    }
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't know when it starts sending. And when it starts I start doing things, when it stops from the "started" state. I have to stop trying to read more. Or perhaps I misunderstood the your code. Can you please explain it?

Comment: You can register SerialEvent.you can get more http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11

Comment: How did you connect with device?